# dynamically created button onclick is not working in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I dynamically create a button element in my javascript function and then add an onclick event to that button. But after I press that button I get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: removeQuestionis not defined` (removeQuestionis is my function name )

this is the button i created inside of my js function

```
const addQuestions = () => {
   const removeBtn = '<a color="primary" onClick={removeQuestion}> x</a>';
   window.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', removeBtn);
};
```

this function are called by onclick

```
const removeQuestion = () => {
        console.log('test')
    };
```

Comment: How are you loading the javascript?

Comment: can you try adding onClick={this.removeQuestion}

Comment: Please, try to add the full example of code.

Comment: Thanks @Mina update my full code related to this issue

Comment: @Suresh i am tryed onClick={this.removeQuestion} but it was not working

Comment: You're using `insertAdjacentHTML` in a React app when you shouldn't be (React deals with DOM updates and doesn't understand when another process interferes). You should add your button to your JSX and show it conditionally based on some state that is triggered at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is issue with `insertAdjacentHTML` i used `React.createElement` and after rendered using `ReactDOM.render`

```
let input = React.createElement("input",{className:"questionTextInput",name:"textInputQuestion[]"},null);
   ReactDOM.render(input,questionPreview);
```

Answer (score 1):

### ReactJS

> Read carefully the [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) part of the React documentation.
>
> React is working using virtual DOM.

```
export default function App() {
  const removeBtns = ['x1', 'x2'];
  const removeQuestion = () => {
    console.log('test');
  };
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      {removeBtns.map((x) => (
        <a key={x} href={'#!'} onClick={removeQuestion}>
          {x}
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

### HTML

Try `onClick="removeQuestion()"` or `onClick={removeQuestion()}`

The value accepted by onclick in html is the javascript statement executed when clicked.

The value accepted by onclick in javascript is the callback function executed when clicked.

```js
const removeBtn1 = '<a onClick={removeQuestion()}> x1 </a>';
const removeBtn2 = '<a onClick="removeQuestion()"> x2 </a>';

const removeQuestion = () => {
  console.log('test')
};

window.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', [removeBtn1, removeBtn2]);
```

Also you can try `EventListener`.

```js
const removeBtn1 = '<a class="btn"> x1 </a>';
const removeBtn2 = '<a class="btn"> x2 </a>';

window.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', [removeBtn1, removeBtn2]);

document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('test');
  });
});
```

Comment: i tryed both of this `onClick="removeQuestion()"` and `onClick={removeQuestion()}` but still getting the same error :(

Comment: @Vivekkalanka Sorry, I didn't notice it was reactjs at first, I re-edited and added an example for your reference

Answer (score 1):

this is issue with `insertAdjacentHTML` you can use ReactDOM.render

```
 let input = React.createElement("input",{className:"questionTextInput",name:"textInputQuestion[]"},null);
   ReactDOM.render(input,questionPreview);
```